# Center Website On All Screen Sizes

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I need help centering my webpage on small screen sizes. My site looks fine at its normal width of 989px, but when it gets smaller it gets pushed to the left and there's a lot of white space on the right. I've been trying many ways to fix this but nothing works.

Now it's up to you guys. Hope you can help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

body{
   text-align:center; /*For IE6 Shenanigans*/
   min-width:989px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

}

#header{background:url(/images/header.png) no-repeat;
border:;
padding:50px 0px 50px 0px;
text-indent:-9999px;
width:100%;
background-size:cover;

}
#menu{background:url(/images/nav-slice.png) repeat-x;
border:;
width:100%;
background-size:100%;
padding-bottom:20px;
padding-top:15px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #888; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #888; 
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px #888; 
}

ul{padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
list-style-type:none;

}

li{

float:left;
display:inline-block;
padding-left:17%;/*70 divided by 800*/
padding-right:8%;
font-size:1em;

}

a.ali{text-decoration:none;
color: white;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:0px;
text-align:center;
font-family:helvetica;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:1em;

}

a.ali:hover{color:blue;
}

#content{

padding:180px 0px 0px 0px;

float:left;
width:100%;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:4.044%;/*40px*/
margin-right:2.022%;/*20px*/
margin-bottom:0px;
}


#footer{background:url(/images/footer-slice.png) repeat-x;
padding:15px 0px 15px 0px;
border:;
float:left;
width:100%;
margin-top:-40px;
}

a.tou{
font-family:arial;
text-size:10px;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}

a.tou:hover{
color:blue;
}

p{
font-family:arial;
text-size:10px;
color:white;

}

#wrapper{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:80%;/*989px*/
max-width:80%;
min-width:989px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888; 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888; 
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

.title{
font-family:myriad pro;
color:#2e4d9b;
position:relative;
bottom:180px;
right:350px;
}

.sales-page{
background:url(/images/sales-page.png) no-repeat;
float:left;
position:relative;
bottom:140px;
left:6%;
padding-top:426px;
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
margin-bottom:-100px;
clear:both;
}

.get-website-now{
background:url(/images/get-website-now.png) no-repeat;
padding-top:40px;
padding-bottom:40px;
padding-left:18.20%;/*180px*/
padding-right:18.20%;
float:left;
position:relative;
bottom:230px;
left:31%;
margin-top:0px;
clear:both;
}
.get-website-now:hover{
opacity:0.9;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
<h1>Your Name And Logo</h1> 
</div><!--end header-->
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a class="ali" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="ali" href="products.php">Products</a></li>
<li><a class="ali" href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div><!--end menu-->
<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">Home</h1>
<div class="sales-page"></div>
<a href="products.php" class="get-website-now" style=""></a>
</div><!--end content-->

<div id="footer">
<p><a class="tou" target="_blank" href="/terms-and-conditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a>&nbspFive80Nine Web Design All Rights Reserved 2013</p>
</div><!--end footer-->
<div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--end wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link to my site: http://webdesign.five80nine.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem but this was not the solution I wanted. I added a table around the wrapper and played around with the width until I found the right width to make the page centered. The page is now centered in all sizes including tablet and mobile sizes.

If anyone else has a better solution I would love to hear it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using % on your width to avoid these kind of problems. Especially on your wrapper use a fixed width instead. Then as what macky nyxzz suggests add

```
margin: 0 auto
```

in your wrapper to make it centered in any screen resolution. I faced this kind of problem before and this was the fix. Here is a link for you to read more about [How to Center a Website With CSS](http://buildinternet.com/2008/11/how-to-center-a-website-with-css/). Hope this helps. :)

UPDATE: you could test your website in different screen resolution [here](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

Comment: That doesn't work either. Like I said, I have tried everything and every time web browser is reduced in width, the page gets pushed to the left and there is white space to the left. Open up the page and reduce the width and you will see what I am talking about: webdesign.five80nine.com

Comment: do you mean when you change the size of the browser? not the screen resolution itself? I've tested your site on different screen resolution  and its already centered. Tested it here http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Comment: I tested it on there as well. Try it again under iphone5 or anything mobile and you will see that the site shifts to the left and has a lot of white space on the right.

Comment: yah.. dealing with mobile compatibility is another thing. I thought the question is for desktop screen resolutions only. Try to re-phrase your question maybe someone knows how to do it.

Comment: Even if you look at it from a 10inch screen there is white space on the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #wrapper{
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

this will center your div in all screen resolutions you forgot to put auto

Comment: I know but I added it right after you told me and it didn't fix it.

Comment: remove your margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto use margin: 0 auto; that will automaticaly center you div in a browser

Comment: remove % in your width use 960px; use pixel instead of percent

Answer (score 0):

Make article tag wraps all documents inside the body then put text align to center in css and all main tags container inside this tags. Put `margin: 0 auto;` while `footer clear: both`.  Don't put `margin 0 auto` to `footer` if it has the same width of your header tags. Then refresh your browser and re-size it. It will place your document to the center.

cheers!

Mokista

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For improve readability, please apply appropriate punctuation to your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer